# Basic Lua/ FREESWITCH array command

Tags: lua, freeswitch

I am new to Lua, and this is an elementary question.

I a Lua script, I am querying the Postgress DB for two records via Freeswitch dbh.
I am able to set the first value as a local variable.
I am stuck at how to set the second value as a variable.

```
local dbh = Database.new('system');
local settings = Settings.new(dbh, A, B);
local sql = "SELECT A, B FROM TABLE WHERE A = '" .. A.."'";
local A = dbh:first_value(sql); --this gets saved correctly
local B = WHAT DO PUT HERE? ; -- Perhaps, I need to create an array instead?

dbh:release()
```

Comment: ```lua
local sql = "SELECT A, B FROM TABLE WHERE A = '" .. A.."'";
```

**Don't do this!** This is the textbook **SQL injection vulnerability**; what if `A` contains single quotes? Usually your program will just break with weird errors, but if `A` is crafted by a malicious actor, they can run  arbitrary queries against your database.

Reading the [freeswitch DBH docs](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Lua+with+Database), I can't find any method for escaping user input or parametrizing SQL queries. This alone is a major reason against using the freeswitch DBH.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a specific row you should do this in the SQL command.

Alternatively you can query the entire table and run through the rows of the result.

I don't know freeswitch but that's what I found here:
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Lua+API+Reference

> **dbh:query("query", function())** takes the query as a string and an optional Lua callback function that is called on each row returned by
> the db. The callback function is passed a table representation of the
> current row for each iteration of the loop.
>
> Syntax of each row is: `{ ["column_name_1"] = "value_1", ["column_name_2"] = "value_2" }`.
>
> If you (optionally) return a number other than 0 from the
> callback-function, you'll break the loop.

In order to use this you should learn how to define functions and how to use function values. Then it should be obvious what to do.

Maybe there is also a function that returns the query result as a table. At least that is the case for many other database interfaces. Ideally you should read the manual of the freeswitch Lua API first. Then you know what commands exist. Together with the Lua manual you'll know how to use them.